# Cassandra float precision

Tags: cassandra, precision, cassandra-3.0

I created float value from a Cassandra table with a float type column.

```
CREATE TABLE testing(
id int,
value float,
primary key (id)
);

INSERT INTO testing(id,  value) VALUES (1, 2341.1);  

SELECT * from testing;
```

I get that the value is 2341.1001

What's wrong with my setting?
Thanks.

Here is my cassandra version.

```
cassandra@cqlsh> show version
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Answer (score 3):

floats & doubles are represented in memory as close approximations to number that you specified as input.  You can find more details about internal representation of floats and doubles in the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).

If you want to have precise numbers you can use `decimal` type, that is mapped into [Java's `BigDecimal` type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), but it use more memory/disk space.